# Limit the visual column width display in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

How to visually limit the display of a column while still allowing the column to store values up to its maximum length in postgresql?

I do not mean truncating it as that is only temporary. When you load the table again, it will show the column's value maximum number of characters.

Eg. Column access_token can have a maximum characters of 100. But I do not want all those 100 characters to be visually displayed every time I run a query on the table that has that column. I want to make it so that I can see only 10 character out of that 100. It is like abbreviating a word.

I remember doing this before but I had forgotten how to. Also , I am using pgAdmin4 version 7.4 and PostgreSQL version 15.3. See screenshots below

What I Don't Want

[image]

What I want

[image]

Comment: Use a different tool, pgAdmin is just one of many clients for PostgreSQL.

Comment: In pgAdmin4 the only thing I know to do is to grab the  right hand column bar in the header and pull it to the left to narrow the column. That does not persist though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out `Preferences > Query Tool > Results Grid`.  There, you can set `Maximum Column Width`.  It doesn't give an option to specify which column to limit, but will likely serve your purpose.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I was searching for but just could not remember how to do it. Now the knowledge is here for others to see :)